# Why is RSpec giving "Attempt to unlock a mutex which is not locked" error when attempting to click_button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm attempting to test links that should/shouldn't be seen when logged in, but RSpec is throwing the following error:

```
Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
ThreadError:
  Attempt to unlock a mutex which is not locked
  # (eval):2:in `click_button'
  # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:5:in `sign_in'
  # ./spec/views/header_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My test block looks like so:

```
describe "when signed in" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  it { should have_link("Sign out") }
  it { should_not have_link("Sign up") }
  it { should_not have_link("Log in") }
end
```

And my sign_in function:

```
def sign_in(user)
  click_link "Log in"
  fill_in "username", with: user.username
  fill_in "password", with: user.password
  click_button "Log me in!"
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

I tried changing out

```
click_button "Log me in!"
```

with

```
find(:button, "Log me in!").click
```

and it results in the following error:

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:
   unexpected '!' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x00000003645778 @type=:DESCENDANT_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000036464e8 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["Log"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000036458b8 @type=:DESCENDANT_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x00000003645f98 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["me"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000036459f8 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["in"]>]>]>]'
 # (eval):3:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
 # (eval):3:in `do_parse'
 # (eval):2:in `find'
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:5:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/views/header_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I then attempted to replace my button text with "Log me in", without the exclamation point,
and Capybara throws an ElementNotFound error:

```
Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "Log me in"
 # (eval):2:in `find'
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:5:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/views/header_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm still pretty new to RSpec and Rails in general, but I've been able to find my way around pretty well so far until now. This one has me completely stumped.

Comment: Does the error still happen if you comment out the last line in `sign_in`?

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili commenting out the line `cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token` still throws the same error. I tried replacing `click_button "Log me in!"` with `find(:button, "Log me in!")` and it results in a very long Nokogiri error related to the exclamation mark at the end. Replacing the button text with just "Log me in", without the exclamation mark, results in the Capybara error `Unable to find css "Log me in"`.

Comment: Same error if you use click_on instead of click_button?

Comment: Is there a reason that your spec (I assume **spec/views/header_spec.rb**) is a view spec and not an integration spec under the **spec/requests** directory?  According to [the RSpec View spec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-2/docs/view-specs/view-spec), view specs "render view templates in isolation", which doesn't seem like what you're doing with the calls to `click_button` and `fill_in`.  Not sure if it will work, but perhaps try moving your specs, or the file itself, to **spec/requests**.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti I actually tried that this afternoon before heading in to work, but no dice. Also, changing `click_button` to `click_to` results in the same error. If it's worth anything, I have another spec that tests the user sign up page, and the `click_button` function works just fine in it. My sign up page uses a `form_for`, while my sign in form is a simple `form_tag`, would that make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after monkeying around a little bit last night, I finally found the solution and promptly began to facedesk. I'm using a SessionsHelper with my SessionsController, and I had my include statement outside of the class:

```
include SessionsHelper

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

By moving the the include statement inside of the class:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper

  def new
  end
  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

All of my tests began to pass. While my tests were failing with the include statement outside of the class block, the actual functionality seemed to be working fine. I could sign in/out, the cookie was being stored with the correct information, and I was seeing no errors whatsoever in the server console.